# JWT Auth doesn't work when __construct method in controller

Tags: laravel, jwt

In a Laravel Application, the JWT middleware doesn't work properly. I found out, that there is no auth check, when the controller has a `__construct` method.

```
class ProjectController extends Controller
{
    public $company;

    public $user;

    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {

        $this->company = $request->user()->company;

        $this->user = $request->user();
    }
```

Api routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'jwt.auth'], function () {
    Route::resource('/projects', 'Project\\ProjectController');
});
```

When i comment the `__construct` method, the system return a 401 as expected. But if the `__construct` method is not commented, the system returns a 500 because the company can not be found.

Why the `__construct` method doesn't work with jwt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the jwt middleware, this is intended behavior from laravel, you can read more about it [here](https://laravel-news.com/controller-construct-session-changes-in-laravel-5-3).

> Laravel collects all route specific middlewares first before running
>   the request through the pipeline, and while collecting the controller
>   middleware an instance of the controller is created, thus the
>   constructor is called, however at this point the request isn’t ready
>   yet.

You can find Taylor's reasoning behind it [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/15072#issuecomment-242769373):

> It’s very bad to use session or auth in your constructor as no request
>   has happened yet and session and auth are INHERENTLY tied to an HTTP
>   request. You should receive this request in an actual controller
>   method which you can call multiple times with multiple different
>   requests. By forcing your controller to resolve session or auth
>   information in the constructor you are now forcing your entire
>   controller to ignore the actual incoming request which can cause
>   significant problems when testing, etc.

So the solution would be to get the user and company from the request in each controller method, but if you want to keep it in the constructor you could implement the following workaround:

```
class ProjectController extends Controller
{
    public $company;

    public $user;

    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
            $this->company = $request->user()->company;

            $this->user = $request->user();

            return $next($request);
        });
    }
}
```